# Using Declare value as a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently creating an on-the-fly table using following

```
DECLARE @startnum INT=1000
DECLARE @endnum INT=1004
;
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
)
SELECT * FROM gen
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

I was wondering if there is a way for me to utilize this table in a subquery for a join. For example how can I replace a2 in the following code withe the table above.

```
select a1.*, a2.*
from
(select 
      1000 as v1
union all
select
      1001 as v1
union all
select
      1003 as v1)a1
left join
(select 
      1000 as v2
union all
select
      1001 as v2
union all
select
      1003 as v2
union all 
select
      1004 as v2)a2
    ON a1.v1=a2.v2
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use that table at all. I would instead use a tally table so you don't have to create it on the fly all the time which can be horribly inefficient (although with only 4 rows it isn't a big deal).

Comment: @Sean Lange thanks for the response. So the on-the-fly table will have more rows than 4 in reality. Can you please show me how to use a tally table in my case to replace a2. It would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

try like below just add another cte and use join

```
DECLARE @startnum INT=1000
DECLARE @endnum INT=1004
;
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
),cte as
(
SELECT * FROM gen

) , cte1 as
(
select a1.* from
(select 
      1000 as v1
union all
select
      1001 as v1
union all
select
      1003 as v1
      )a1

) select cte.*,cte1.* from cte join cte1 on cte.num=cte1.v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH gen AS (
      SELECT @startnum AS num
      UNION ALL
      SELECT num + 1
      FROM gen
      WHERE num + 1 <= @endnum
     )
SELECT
FROM gen JOIN
     a1
     ON a1.v1 = gen.num
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The only real trick is that the `OPTION` needs to be at the end of the entire query.